# simple html dom - space in class name

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I'm using PHP Simple HTML DOM to get element from a source code of a site (not mine) and when I find a ul class that is called "board List",this is not found.I think it might be a problem of space but I don't know how to solve it.

this is a piece of php code:

```
$html = str_get_html($result['content']); //get the html of the site
$board = $html->find('.board List');  //  Find all element which class=board List,but in my case it doesn't work,with other class name it works
```

and this is a piece of html code of the site:

```
<!-- OTHER HTML CODE BEFORE THIS --><ul class="board List"><li id="c111131" class="skin_tbl">
<table class="mback" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" onclick="toggleCat('c111131')"><tr>
<td class="mback_left"><div class="plus"></div><td class="mback_center"><h2 class="mtitle">presentiamoci</h2><td class="mback_right"><span id="img_c111131"></span></table>
<div class="mainbg">
<div class="title top"><div class="aa"></div><div class="bb">Forum</div><div class="yy">Statistiche</div><div class="zz">Ultimo Messaggio</div></div>
<ul class="big_list"><!-- OTHER HTML AFTER THIS -->
```

Comment: Class names don't have spaces. The `ul` actually has two separate classes (`board` and `List`). I'm not familiar with the parser you're using, but I'm assuming your second line should be `$board = $html->find('.board.List');`

Comment: @Sadiq Your comment is correct, you should post it as an answer. The parser uses syntax similar to CSS selectors.

Comment: @Sadiq: I tried as you say but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Roran In that case, I would suggest reading the parser's documentation to find the correct syntax for selecting elements that have both classes. Unfortunately, I can't provide much help, since I'm not familiar with the parser as I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by removing board from the find parameter,as this:

```
$board = $html->find('.List');
```

now the parser seems to work correctly

Answer (score 2):

With simple you would probably want to use:

```
$html->find('*[class="board List"]', 0);
```

If you really want to use:

```
$html->find('.board.List', 0);
```

Then [use this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/?source=directory).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that: You cannot use spaces in classnames. spaces are the seperaters of classes

if you have `<div class="container wrapper-something anothersomething"></div>` then you can use `.container`, `.wrapper-something` or `.anothersomething` as a selector and you allways match that div.

So in your code you have `<ul class="board List">`, so to get a match in a css-selector (`$html->find('{here_comes_the_css_selector}');`) you can use eather `.board` or `.List` as the selctor

Therefor your line `$board = $html->find('.board List');` should look more like this:

```
$board = $html->find('.board.List');
// maches every element who has class 'board' AND 'List'
// Here it is really important that there is no spaces between those 2 selectors

// or

$board = $html->find('.List');
// maches every element who has class 'List'

// or

$board = $html->find('.board');
// maches every element who has class 'board'
```

Comment: Have you tried this? Simple won't let you select it that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$board = $html->find('[class="board List"]');
```

With this syntax SimpleHTMLDOM finds elements with multiple class attribute

Comment: Please elaborate your answer.