# PHP Simple DOM Parser Returning Booleans/Null in Scraping Method

Tags: php

Currently trying to scrape some HTML using a DOM scraping library called PHP Simple HTML Dom Parser.

I have the following method:

```
public function getFourLevels() {
    // Iterate through the four pollen levels [Wunderground only has four day
    // pollen prediction]
    for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {

        // Get the raw level
        $rawLevels = $this->html
            ->find("td.text-center.even-four", $i)
            ->plaintext;

        // Clean the raw level
        $level = substr(
            $rawLevels,
            PollenBuddy::LEVELS
        );

        // Push each date to the dates array
        array_push($this->levels, $level);
    }

    return $this->levels;
}
```

The above method is my attempt at scraping the following HTML:

```
    <td class="text-center even-four">
    <strong>Sunday</strong>
    <div>February 15, 2015</div>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center even-four">
    <strong>Monday</strong>
    <div>February 16, 2015</div>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center even-four">
    <strong>Tuesday</strong>
    <div>February 17, 2015</div>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center even-four">
    <strong>Wednesday</strong>
    <div>February 18, 2015</div>
    </td>
```

Here is the source [document](http://view-source:http://www.wunderground.com/DisplayPollen.asp?Zipcode=19104).

The result I get from the above function using `var_dump` is:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  bool(false)
  [1]=>
  bool(false)
  [2]=>
  bool(false)
  [3]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Not quite sure what the issue. If someone could offer me some advice - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
        // Get the raw level
        $rawLevel = $this->html
            ->find("td.even-four", $i)
            ->plaintext;
```

Returns the right data.

Found from this link: [simple html dom - space in class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417424/simple-html-dom-space-in-class-name)