# Simple HTML DOM spaces into class

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I'm using Simple HTML DOM to get elements from a website, but when class attribute has spaces, I don't get anything.

#### Source HTML from [betaexplorer.com](http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/premier-league/standings/?table=table&table_sub=home&ts=WOO1nDO2&dcheck=0)

```
<table id="table-type-2" class="stats-table stats-main table-2">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="odd glib-participant-ppjDR086" data-def-order="0">
        <td class="rank col_rank no" title="">1.</td>
        <td class="participant_name col_participant_name col_name"><span class="team_name_span"><a onclick="javascript:getUrlByWinType('/soccer/england/premier-league/teaminfo.php?team_id=ppjDR086');">Manchester United</a></span></td>
        <td class="matches_played col_matches_played">4</td>
        <td class="wins col_wins">4</td>
        <td class="draws col_draws">0</td>
        <td class="losses col_losses">0</td>
        <td class="goals col_goals">14:0</td>
        <td class="goals col_goals">12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even glib-participant-hA1Zm19f" data-def-order="1">
        <td class="rank col_rank no" title="">2.</td>
        <td class="participant_name col_participant_name col_name"><span class="team_name_span"><a onclick="javascript:getUrlByWinType('/soccer/england/premier-league/teaminfo.php?team_id=hA1Zm19f');">Arsenal</a></span></td>
        <td class="matches_played col_matches_played">4</td>
        <td class="wins col_wins">4</td>
        <td class="draws col_draws">0</td>
        <td class="losses col_losses">0</td>
        <td class="goals col_goals">11:3</td>
        <td class="goals col_goals">12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd glib-participant-Wtn9Stg0" data-def-order="2">
        <td class="rank col_rank no" title="">3.</td>
        <td class="participant_name col_participant_name col_name"><span class="team_name_span"><a onclick="javascript:getUrlByWinType('/soccer/england/premier-league/teaminfo.php?team_id=Wtn9Stg0');">Manchester City</a></span></td>
        <td class="matches_played col_matches_played">4</td>
        <td class="wins col_wins">3</td>
        <td class="draws col_draws">1</td>
        <td class="losses col_losses">0</td>
        <td class="goals col_goals">18:3</td>
        <td class="goals col_goals">10</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### My PHP code using SimpleHtmlDom

```
    <?php
include('../simple_html_dom.php');


function getHTML($url,$timeout)
{
       $ch = curl_init($url); // initialize curl with given url
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]); // set  useragent
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // write the response to a variable
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow redirects if any
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); // max. seconds to execute
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); // stop when it encounters an error
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
       return @curl_exec($ch);
}



$response=getHTML("http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/premier-league/standings/?table=table&table_sub=home&ts=WOO1nDO2&dcheck=0",10);
$html = str_get_html($response);

$team = $html->find("span[class=team_name_span]/a"); 
$numbermatch = $html->find("td.matches_played.col_matches_played"); 
$wins = $html->find("td.wins.col_wins"); 
$draws = $html->find("td.draws.col_draws"); 
$losses = $html->find("td.losses.col_losses"); 
$goals = $html->find("td.goals.col_goals"); 

?>

<table border="1" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Team</th>
            <th>MP</th>
            <th>W</th>
            <th>D</th>
            <th>L</th>
            <th>G</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

<?php



foreach ($team as $match) {


echo  "<tr>".

            "<td class='first-cell'>".$match->innertext."</td> "  .
            "<td class='first-cell'>".$numbermatch->innertext."</td> "  .
            "<td class='first-cell'>".$wins->innertext."</td> "  .
            "<td class='first-cell'>".$draws->innertext."</td> "  .
            "<td class='first-cell'>".$losses->innertext."</td> "  .
            "<td class='first-cell'>".$goals->innertext."</td> "  .


            "</tr><br/>";



        }       



?>
</table>
```

So, I only get first value (because class name is without spaces), but I can't get the rest of values

**EDIT:** I fixed a mistake into PHP code. See again

**EDIT2:** It's not a duplicate, I tried that solution but It doesn't work

**EDIT3:** I tried to use advanced_html_dom (it should fix spaces problem), but I don't get anything (also just the only one I was getting)

**EDIT4:** In the screens below you can see what I'd like to get and what I get right now:

[image: Original]

[image: My screen]

**EDIT5**

team.php

```
    <?php

// START team.php 
class Team
{
    public $name, $matches, $wins, $draws, $losses, $goals;

    public static function parseRow($row): ?self
    {
        $result = new self();
        $result->name = $result->parseMatch($row, 'span.team_name_span a');
        if (null === $result->name) {
            return null; // couldn't even match the name, probably not a team row, skip it
        }

        $result->matches = $result->parseMatch($row, 'td.col_matches_played');
        $result->wins = $result->parseMatch($row, 'td.col_wins');
        $result->draws = $result->parseMatch($row, 'td.col_draws');
        $result->losses = $result->parseMatch($row, 'td.col_losses');
        $result->goals = $result->parseMatch($row, 'td.col_goals');

        return $result;
    }

    private function parseMatch($row, $selector)
    {
        if (!empty($match = $row->find($selector, 0))) {
            return $match->innertext;
        }

        return null;
    }
}

// END team.php

?>
```

clas.php

```
    <?php

include('../simple_html_dom.php');
include('../team.php');


function getHTML($url,$timeout)
{
       $ch = curl_init($url); // initialize curl with given url
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]); // set  useragent
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // write the response to a variable
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow redirects if any
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); // max. seconds to execute
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); // stop when it encounters an error
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
       return @curl_exec($ch);
}



$response=getHTML("http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/premier-league/standings/?table=table&table_sub=home&ts=WOO1nDO2&dcheck=0",10);
$html = str_get_html($response);



// START DOM parsing block
$teams = [];

foreach($html->find('table.stats-table tr') as $row) {
    $team = Team::parseRow($row); // load the row into a Team object if possible

    // skipp this entry if it couldn't match the row
    if (null !== $team) {
        // what were actually doing here is just the OOP equivalent of:
        // $teams[] = ['name' => $row->find('span.team_name_span a',0)->innertext, ...];
        $teams[] = $team;
    }
}

foreach($teams as $team) {
    echo $team->name;
    echo $team->matches;
}

// END DOM Parsing Block

?>
```

Comment: Well then properly quote the class name string in the attribute selector ...?

Comment: try to use %20 instead of space or put it in quote

Comment: What `$html->find()` this functin does?

Comment: I fixed a mistake into PHP code, see again please

Comment: @CBroe Sorry but I don't understand your request

Comment: @MohammedAhmed I tried but nothing

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay They find all html code with that tags

Comment: Possible duplicate of [simple html dom - space in class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417424/simple-html-dom-space-in-class-name)

Comment: @CBroe It's not a duplicate, I tried that solution but it doesn't work

Comment: Show us what you have tried then, edit your question.

Comment: Since all those TDs seem to have "redundant" class information - always `foo` and `col_foo` - you should not even need to specifically select them by _both_ of those classes, a simple `td.matches_played` should do.

Comment: @CBroe I tried this: $numbermatch = $html->find('td.matches_played'); 
but it's not working. I edited my question

Comment: And you have _verified_ that the HTML string you are using to initialize the DOM parser actually contains those elements?

Comment: @CBroe How can I do it, please? which code do it? is it after $html = str_get_html($response);   ?

Comment: No, I meant the content of `$response`.

Comment: @CBroe The code is all there... with class without spaces it's working... I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/cq54-hta2

## Class-names don't have spaces, don't try to match them

SimpleHtmlDom doesn't support attribute selectors like this. Plus you're tyring to match a class as though it has spaces in the class name. So, instead of this:

```
$wins = $html->find("td[class=wins col_wins]"); 
$draws = $html->find("td[class=draws col_draws]"); 
$losses = $html->find("td[class=losses col_losses]");
```

Do the following to match td elements which match BOTH of two class-names:

```
$wins = $html->find("td.wins.col_wins"); 
$draws = $html->find("td.draws.col_draws"); 
$losses = $html->find("td.losses.col_losses");
```

Additionally, that HTML markup doesn't require you to match both classes to get the data, should you could simply do:

```
$wins = $html->find("td.col_wins"); 
$draws = $html->find("td.col_draws"); 
$losses = $html->find("td.col_losses");
```

## Getting repeated selectors (looping through rows).

What you are trying to extract is the an array of data from the rows of a table. More specifically, something that looks like this:

```
$teams = [
    ['Arsenal', matches, wins, ...],
    ['Liverpool', matches, wins, ...],
    ...
];
```

This means you'll need to run the same data-extraction against each row of the table. SimpleHtmlDom makes this easy through jQuery-like `find` methods, which can be called from any matched element.

#### Complete Solution

This solution actually defines a `Team` object to load each row's data into. Should make future adjustments much simpler.

The important piece to note here, is that first we loop through every table-row as `$row`, and collect the team and numbers from `$row->find([selector])`.

```
// START team.php 
class Team
{
    public $name, $matches, $wins, $draws, $losses, $goals;

    public function __construct($row)
    {
        $this->name = $this->parseMatch($row, 'span.team_name_span a');
        if (null === $this->name) {
            return; // couldn't even match the name, probably not a team row, skip it
        }

        $this->matches = $this->parseMatch($row, 'td.col_matches_played');
        $this->wins = $this->parseMatch($row, 'td.col_wins');
        $this->draws = $this->parseMatch($row, 'td.col_draws');
        $this->losses = $this->parseMatch($row, 'td.col_losses');
        $this->goals = $this->parseMatch($row, 'td.col_goals');
    }

    private function parseMatch($row, $selector)
    {
        if (!empty($match = $row->find($selector, 0))) {
            return $match->innertext;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public function isValid()
    {
        return null !== $this->name;
    }

    public function getMatchData() //example
    {
        return "<br><b>". $this->wins .' : '. $this->matches . "</b>";
    }
}

// END team.php

// START DOM parsing block
$teams = [];

foreach($html->find('table.stats-table tr') as $row) {
    $team = new Team($row); // load the row into a Team object if possible

    // skipp this entry if it couldn't match the row
    if ($team->isValid()) {
        // what were actually doing here is just the OOP equivalent of:
        // $teams[] = ['name' => $row->find('span.team_name_span a',0)->innertext, ...];
        $teams[] = $team;
    }
}

foreach($teams as $team) {
    echo "<h1>".$team->name."</h1>";
    echo $team->losses;
    echo $team->getMatchData();
}

// END DOM Parsing Block
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have a question: I have to use them with simple html dom or with advanced html dom?

Comment: Doesn't matter much. [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find) supports it. There are many different projects that use the name "AdvancedHtmlDom", but I suspect they would support it as well.

Comment: Sorry but it's not working. I still get just first value. I need to change something in my code that is in my question?

Comment: If you're trying to access multiple rows of this kind of data, please provide the whole table, with 3 or 4 rows of what you're trying to match.  Please format the HTML properly, rather than putting it all in one line.

Comment: I edited my question. I added screenshot about what I'd like to get and what I get at the moment.  I added in my code the source link. Could you check it, please? Thanks

Comment: When I was asking for html, I meant the source HTML you're trying to parse. The reason being that you'll have to run those parse commands against each row of the data you're parsing. Something like `$rows = $html->find('table.teams tr'); ... $wins = $row->find('...');`. I need a better idea of that source structure before I can make a reliable suggestion.

Comment: ok, maybe I understood. This is the page: http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/premier-league/standings/?table=table&table_sub=home&ts=WOO1nDO2&dcheck=0

Comment: and this is the source link: view-source:http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/premier-league/standings/?table=table&table_sub=home&ts=WOO1nDO2&dcheck=0

Comment: I hope It's what you asked :)

Comment: @James69, updated answer. This should get you there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I saw your code but I don't know how to implement it into my code, especially about source link... where I should put it in your code? sorry for my question :)

Comment: To be done properly, put the whole `Team` class in it's own file `team.php`, and include it like you did `simple_html_dom.php`. The rest should replace everything after your `$html = str_get_html($response);` For the sake of simplicity, I've adjusted the sample code with comments to more clearly show the different blocks of code.

Comment: It's not working. I edited my post, check EDIT5, please, I posted full code about team.php and clas.php (where I have str_get_html and other). Thanks

Comment: @James69, You really need to get better about describing things. What would you do if your boss said, "the site isn't working?" Be as specific as you can when describing problems, because "not working" doesn't help anyone. Added a phpfiddle for you: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/cq54-hta2

Comment: The code is perfect! And you're right, I'll try to be more specific. Thanks for your help and for your advice!